# Get rows with max value having 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this PL/SQL query:

```
SELECT customer_id, table_id, count(table_id) as reserved
FROM { derived table }
GROUP BY customer_id,table_id
ORDER BY reserved DESC
```

I have this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATfUw.png

So now I want to get the first 2 rows (with max value according to `reserved` column), I tried this query:

```
SELECT customer_id,table_id,max(reserved) from
(
    SELECT customer_id, table_id, count(table_id) as reserved
    FROM { derived table }
    GROUP BY customer_id,table_id
    ORDER BY reserved DESC
)
GROUP BY customer_id, table_id
```

I recieved same result as above...

**Note:** Result was just example, maybe there will be 3, 1 or more rows with max value, next time

Comment: `SELECT TOP 2 customer_id, table_id, count(table_id) as reserved
FROM { derived table }
GROUP BY customer_id,table_id
ORDER BY reserved DESC`?

Comment: You are grouping by the same fields in your subquery as you are in your outer query, so there's no difference between COUNT() and MAX() in that case.

Comment: Well i want to group by table_id... but pl/sql wont let me keep the customer_id's
So i must put customer_id in group by clause

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT customer_id,table_id,reserved
FROM (SELECT customer_id,table_id, COUNT(*)as reserved, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS ct_rank
      FROM { derived table }
      GROUP BY customer_id,table_id
      )sub
WHERE ct_rank = 1
```

Edit: Changed to use Rank

Comment: Well isn't this a little.. too much copy/paste, if derived table has large query, copy and pasting wouldn't be practical... i would like some way around if possible..

Comment: Can you do this with alias `reserved` since it (presumably) isn't an actual column name?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a rank to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want the first 2 rows, I assume you don't mean you always want the first 2 rows - but rather you want the rows which have the maximum value of 'reserved'.

You could try:

```
    SELECT customer_id, table_id, count(table_id) as reserved
    FROM { derived table }
    GROUP BY customer_id, table_id
    HAVING count(table_id) = (
        SELECT top 1 count(table_id)
        FROM { derived table }
        GROUP BY customer_id, table_id
        ORDER BY reserved DESC
    )
```

I know that would work in T-SQL and I'm guessing it should in PL/SQL as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the `TOP` keyword isn't part of the Oracle SQL syntax. TOP does make this sort of thing a lot simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very close.  The outer query should be selecting two rows, rather than re-doing the aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id, table_id, reserved from
(
    SELECT customer_id, table_id, count(table_id) as reserved
    GROUP BY customer_id,table_id
    ORDER BY reserved DESC
)
where rownum <= 2;
```